# Text select able but not editable in the textView

Tags: android, textview, jquery-ui-selectable

I want the text in the textView **select able, copy able but not paste or writable.** I want to prevent user writing or pasting over the existing text. How can I do that?

I have used the following code in the xml but it doesn't serve the purpose.

```
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_body_story"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_body_story"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffee04"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: If I enable text selectable then it is copyable and editable (user can write whatever he wishes; though it vanishes when activity closes) . But I want that a user can only select and copy the text but not edit or write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `android:inputType` attribute from your `TextView`. Having an input type is what's allowing the user to modify the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:inputType="none"
```